# Convert .pyc file to .py file with uncompyle6 (bad marshal data error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, reverse-engineering

I am trying to convert the **flag.pyc** file to **flag.py** file.
Here is my procedures: **flag.pyc** -> **flag.pyasm** -> **flag2.pyc** -> **flag.py**
However, the final step(**flag2.pyc** -> **flag.py**) generates **bad marshal data error**
In order to identify the problem, i have double checked the **flag2.pyc** file. I have found that **flag2.pyc** is different from **flag.pyc**. And since **.pyc** file is difficult to read, i have decided to convert **flag2.pyc** to **flag2.pyasm** to see the difference between **flag.pyasm** and **flag2.pyasm**. However, it gives me a similar error.

Here is how the each file be generated:
**flag.pyc** is the original **.pyc** file.
**flag.pyasm** is generated by **flag.pyc** with `xdis` and `xasm`
**flag2.pyc** is generated by **flag.pyasm** with `xdis` and `xasm`
**flag2.pyasm** is generated by **flag2.pyc** with `xdis` and `xasm`
**flag.py** is generated by **flag2.pyc** with `uncompyle6`

Here are the commands for each procedure:
1. **flag.pyc** -> **flag.pyasm**  `pydisasm --asm flag.pyc > flag.pyasm`
2. **flag.pyasm** -> **flag2.pyc** `./xasm/xasm_cli.py flag.pyasm`
3. **flag2.pyc** -> **flag2.pyasm**  `pydisasm --asm flag2.pyc > flag2.pyasm`
4. **flag2.pyc** -> **flag.py** `uncompyle6 flag2.pyc`

The first step and second step work fine.
However, the third and fourth step give me a similar error(**bad marshal data error**).

Here is the third step's error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xdis/load.py", line 242, in load_module_from_file_object
    co = marshal.loads(bytecode)
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xdis/load.py", line 242, in load_module_from_file_object
    co = marshal.loads(bytecode)
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/pydisasm", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.cae(self.cae(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xdis/bin/pydisasm.py", line 75, in main
    disassemble_file(path, sys.stdout, asm, header, show_bytes)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xdis/main.py", line 270, in disassemble_file
    version, timestamp, magic_int, co, is_pypy, source_size, sip_hash = load_module(filename)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xdis/load.py", line 135, in load_module
    return load_module_from_file_object(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xdis/load.py", line 255, in load_module_from_file_object
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Ill-formed bytecode file /Users/frank/Desktop/python-xasm/xasm/flag2.pyc
<class 'ValueError'>; bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```

My environment is MacOs.My python version is **3.8.0** with **newest** `xdis`, `xasm`, `uncompyle6`
Any suggestions?